# I18n Problems / Exceptions when starting cheat sheet Test

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, functional-testing, jubula

i'm evaluating the GUI Test Tool Jubula at moment. While working my way through the cheat sheet, i stumbeld into some Errors i don't really understand.

I work through the cheet sheet and when i try to start the tests nothing happens. The following Stacktraces are printed to the clinet logfile. Has anybody encountered these Errors before and give me a hint, how to solve these?

---

```
2012-11-12 09:11:01.323 [ModalContext] ERROR o.e.jubula.tools.i18n.CompSystemI18n - Cannot find I18N-key in resource bundles: 1
java.util.MissingResourceException: No entry found for key: 1
    at org.eclipse.jubula.tools.i18n.CompSystemI18n.getStringInternal(CompSystemI18n.java:128) ~[org.eclipse.jubula.tools_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.tools.i18n.CompSystemI18n.getString(CompSystemI18n.java:80) ~[org.eclipse.jubula.tools_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.utils.StringHelper.initMap(StringHelper.java:154) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.utils.StringHelper.(StringHelper.java:56) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.utils.StringHelper.getInstance(StringHelper.java:85) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.businessprocess.ComponentNamesBP.initDefaultNames(ComponentNamesBP.java:743) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.businessprocess.ComponentNamesBP.(ComponentNamesBP.java:158) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.businessprocess.ComponentNamesBP.getInstance(ComponentNamesBP.java:167) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.persistence.ProjectPM.loadProjectInROSession(ProjectPM.java:507) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.ui.rcp.handlers.project.OpenProjectHandler$OpenProjectOperation.load(OpenProjectHandler.java:274) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.ui.rcp_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.ui.rcp.handlers.project.OpenProjectHandler$OpenProjectOperation.run(OpenProjectHandler.java:121) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.ui.rcp_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121) [org.eclipse.jface_3.7.0.v20110928-1505.jar:na]
2012-11-12 09:11:01.339 [ModalContext] ERROR o.e.jubula.tools.i18n.CompSystemI18n - Cannot find I18N-key in resource bundles: 2
java.util.MissingResourceException: No entry found for key: 2
    at org.eclipse.jubula.tools.i18n.CompSystemI18n.getStringInternal(CompSystemI18n.java:128) ~[org.eclipse.jubula.tools_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.tools.i18n.CompSystemI18n.getString(CompSystemI18n.java:80) ~[org.eclipse.jubula.tools_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.utils.StringHelper.initMap(StringHelper.java:154) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.utils.StringHelper.(StringHelper.java:56) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.utils.StringHelper.getInstance(StringHelper.java:85) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.businessprocess.ComponentNamesBP.initDefaultNames(ComponentNamesBP.java:743) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.businessprocess.ComponentNamesBP.(ComponentNamesBP.java:158) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.businessprocess.ComponentNamesBP.getInstance(ComponentNamesBP.java:167) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.persistence.ProjectPM.loadProjectInROSession(ProjectPM.java:507) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.ui.rcp.handlers.project.OpenProjectHandler$OpenProjectOperation.load(OpenProjectHandler.java:274) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.ui.rcp_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.ui.rcp.handlers.project.OpenProjectHandler$OpenProjectOperation.run(OpenProjectHandler.java:121) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.ui.rcp_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121) [org.eclipse.jface_3.7.0.v20110928-1505.jar:na]
2012-11-12 09:11:01.339 [ModalContext] ERROR o.e.jubula.tools.i18n.CompSystemI18n - Cannot find I18N-key in resource bundles: 3
java.util.MissingResourceException: No entry found for key: 3
    at org.eclipse.jubula.tools.i18n.CompSystemI18n.getStringInternal(CompSystemI18n.java:128) ~[org.eclipse.jubula.tools_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.tools.i18n.CompSystemI18n.getString(CompSystemI18n.java:80) ~[org.eclipse.jubula.tools_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.utils.StringHelper.initMap(StringHelper.java:154) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.utils.StringHelper.(StringHelper.java:56) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.utils.StringHelper.getInstance(StringHelper.java:85) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.businessprocess.ComponentNamesBP.initDefaultNames(ComponentNamesBP.java:743) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.businessprocess.ComponentNamesBP.(ComponentNamesBP.java:158) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.businessprocess.ComponentNamesBP.getInstance(ComponentNamesBP.java:167) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.persistence.ProjectPM.loadProjectInROSession(ProjectPM.java:507) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.ui.rcp.handlers.project.OpenProjectHandler$OpenProjectOperation.load(OpenProjectHandler.java:274) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.ui.rcp_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.ui.rcp.handlers.project.OpenProjectHandler$OpenProjectOperation.run(OpenProjectHandler.java:121) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.ui.rcp_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121) [org.eclipse.jface_3.7.0.v20110928-1505.jar:na]
2012-11-12 09:11:01.339 [ModalContext] ERROR o.e.jubula.tools.i18n.CompSystemI18n - Cannot find I18N-key in resource bundles: percent
java.util.MissingResourceException: No entry found for key: percent
    at org.eclipse.jubula.tools.i18n.CompSystemI18n.getStringInternal(CompSystemI18n.java:128) ~[org.eclipse.jubula.tools_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.tools.i18n.CompSystemI18n.getString(CompSystemI18n.java:80) ~[org.eclipse.jubula.tools_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.utils.StringHelper.initMap(StringHelper.java:154) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.utils.StringHelper.(StringHelper.java:56) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.utils.StringHelper.getInstance(StringHelper.java:85) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.businessprocess.ComponentNamesBP.initDefaultNames(ComponentNamesBP.java:743) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.businessprocess.ComponentNamesBP.(ComponentNamesBP.java:158) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.businessprocess.ComponentNamesBP.getInstance(ComponentNamesBP.java:167) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.persistence.ProjectPM.loadProjectInROSession(ProjectPM.java:507) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.core_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.ui.rcp.handlers.project.OpenProjectHandler$OpenProjectOperation.load(OpenProjectHandler.java:274) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.ui.rcp_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jubula.client.ui.rcp.handlers.project.OpenProjectHandler$OpenProjectOperation.run(OpenProjectHandler.java:121) [org.eclipse.jubula.client.ui.rcp_1.3.0.201210161256.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121) [org.eclipse.jface_3.7.0.v20110928-1505.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug entry for this in the Jubula Bugzilla. It's been fixed in the current development stand and will be released with the Kepler version. It's nothing critical, but does make the log file fuller:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=393124